# How to scrape table by keyword in 'th' statement

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape a table based on the key word of the 'th' element nested in a 'tr'. Reason is table will vary by content order but keywords will remain the same. I would like to scrape table when 'th' text equals 'Product Number' and retrieve the 'td' text. The table is ordered by 'tr' elements. I have come close but not correct.

URL - [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07G5MZNJ4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07G5MZNJ4)

I have tried the following, it works by providing the text of the first 'td' in the first 'tr' of the table. I would like to know where I insert something like "find 'tr' when 'th' = 'Part Number' return text of 'td'. Of note, 'th' and 'td' are nested under 'tr'

```
 try:
   table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'product-specification-table'})
   mfg1 = table.find('tr')
   MFG_NO = mfg1.find('td').text.strip()       

 except:
    pass
```

I expect to have the text of 'td' when 'th' contains 'Part Number' . Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression to find text and then find_next('td') tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
data=requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07G5MZNJ4').text
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'product-specification-table'})
item=table.find('th',text=re.compile('Part Number'))
MFG_NO=item.find_next('td').text
print(MFG_NO.strip())
```

### Output:

```
PV-923/1
```

Comment: I find this approach good when element exists on pages in different locations but identical statement, I am able to specify the location.

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be to use :contains with bs4 4.7.1 and then get the next sibling td using combinator

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07G5MZNJ4/?tag=stackoverfl08-20', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

if soup.select_one('title').text == 'Robot Check':
    print('bad luck')
else:
    part_number = soup.select_one('th:contains("Part Number") + td')
    if part_number is None:
        part_number = 'Not found'
    else:
        part_number = part_number.text.strip()
    print(part_number)
```

Comment: I tested it and it does. Have you checked the response in case you got a bot check?

Comment: I have added a couple of lines to demo this. Run once as is then change the User-Agent to Mozilla/4.0  and run again

Comment: Amazing. Yes it works. Really impressed with the ':contains' ability. THANK YOU

Comment: I find this approach good when element is located in only one place on pages and I do not need to specify multiple locations.

Comment: yup. There is still usually a way even if value occurs in more than one place.